# Laravel REST API and high CPU load

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel-4, cpu-usage

I am developing a simple RESTful API using Laravel 4.
I have set a `Route` that calls a function of my `Controller` that basically does this:

- If information is in the database, pack it in a JSON object and return a response
- Else try to download it (html/xml parsing), store it and finally pack the JSON response and send it.

I have noticed that the CPU load while doing a total of 1700 requests, only 2 at a time together, raises to 70-90%.

I am a complete php and laravel beginner and I've made the API following [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/laravel-4-a-start-at-a-restful-api-updated--net-29785), maybe I'm probably doing something wrong or it's just a proof of concept lacking of optimzations. How can I improve this code? (starting function is `getGames`)
Do you think the root of all problems is Laravel or I should obtain the same result even changing framework/using raw PHP?

**UPDATE1** I also set a file Cache, but the CPU load is still ~50%.

**UPDATE2** I set the query rate at two each 500ms and the CPU load lowered at 12%, so I guess this code is missing queue handling or something like this.

```
class GameController extends BaseController{
    private static $platforms=array(
        "Atari 2600",
        "Commodore 64",
        "Sega Dreamcast",
        "Sega Game Gear",
        "Nintendo Game Boy",
        "Nintendo Game Boy Color",
        "Nintendo Game Boy Advance",
        "Atari Lynx",
        "M.A.M.E.",
        "Sega Mega Drive",
        "Colecovision",
        "Nintendo 64",
        "Nintendo DS",
        "Nintendo Entertainment System (NES)",
        "Neo Geo Pocket",
        "Turbografx 16",
        "Sony PSP",
        "Sony PlayStation",
        "Sega Master System",
        "Super Nintendo (SNES)",
        "Nintendo Virtualboy",
        "Wonderswan");
    private function getDataTGDB($name,$platform){
        $url = 'http://thegamesdb.net/api/GetGame.php?';
        if(null==$name || null==$platform) return NULL;
        $url.='name='.urlencode($name);
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
        $data=new Data;
        $data->query=$name;
        $resultPlatform = (string)$xml->Game->Platform;

        $data->platform=$platform;
        $data->save();
        foreach($xml->Game as $entry){
            $games = Game::where('gameid',(string)$entry->id)->get();
            if($games->count()==0){
                if(strcasecmp($platform , $entry->Platform)==0 || 
                (strcasecmp($platform ,"Sega Mega Drive")==0 && 
                ($entry->Platform=="Sega Genesis" || 
                $entry->Platform=="Sega 32X" || 
                $entry->Platform=="Sega CD"))){
                    $game = new Game;
                    $game->gameid = (string)$entry->id;
                    $game->title = (string)$entry->GameTitle;
                    $game->releasedate = (string)$entry->ReleaseDate;
                    $genres='';
                    if(NULL!=$entry->Genres->genre)
                    foreach($entry->Genres->genre as $genre){
                        $genres.=$genre.',';
                    }
                    $game->genres=$genres;
                    unset($genres);
                    $game->description = (string)$entry->Overview;
                    foreach($entry->Images->boxart as $boxart){
                        if($boxart["side"]=="front"){
                            $game->bigcoverurl = (string)$boxart;
                            $game->coverurl = (string) $boxart["thumb"];
                        } continue;
                    }
                    $game->save();
                    $data->games()->attach($game->id);
                } 
            }
            else foreach($games as $game){
                $data->games()->attach($game->id);
            }
        }
        unset($xml);
        unset($url);
        return $this->printJsonArray($data);
    }

    private function getArcadeHits($name){
        $url = "http://www.arcadehits.net/index.php?p=roms&jeu=";
        $url .=urlencode($name);

        $html = file_get_html($url);

        $data = new Data;
        $data->query=$name;
        $data->platform='M.A.M.E.';
        $data->save();
        $games = Game::where('title',$name)->get();
        if($games->count()==0){
            $game=new Game;
            $game->gameid = -1;
            $title = $html->find('h4',0)->plaintext;
            if("Derniers jeux commentés"==$title)
            { 
                unset($game);
                return Response::json(array('status'=>'404'),200);
            }
            else{
                $game->title=$title;
                $game->description="(No description.)";
                $game->releasedate=$html->find('a[href*=yearz]',0)->plaintext;
                $game->genres = $html->find('a[href*=genre]',0)->plaintext;
                $minithumb = $html->find('img.minithumb',0);
                $game->coverurl = $minithumb->src;
                $game->bigcoverurl = str_replace("/thumb/","/jpeg/",$minithumb->src);
                $game->save();
                $data->games()->attach($game->id);
            }
        }

        unset($html);
        unset($url);
        return $this->printJsonArray($data);
    }

    private function printJsonArray($data){
        $games = $data->games()->get();
        $array_games = array();
        foreach($games as $game){
            $array_games[]=array(
                'GameTitle'=>$game->title,
                'ReleaseDate'=>$game->releasedate,
                'Genres'=>$game->genres,
                'Overview'=>$game->description,
                'CoverURL'=>$game->coverurl,
                'BigCoverURL'=>$game->bigcoverurl
            );
        }
        $result = Response::json(array(
            'status'=>'200',
            'Game'=>$array_games
            ),200);
        $key = $data->query.$data->platform;
        if(!Cache::has($key))
            Cache::put($key,$result,1440);
        return $result;
    }

    private static $baseImgUrl = "";
    public function getGames($apikey,$title,$platform){
            $key = $title.$platform;
            if(Cache::has($key)) return Cache::get($key);
        if(!in_array($platform,GameController::$platforms)) return Response::json(array("status"=>"403","message"=>"non valid platform"));
        $datas = Data::where('query',$title)
                ->where('platform',$platform)
                ->get();
        //If this query has already been done we return data,otherwise according to $platform
        //we call the proper parser.
        if($datas->count()==0){
            if("M.A.M.E."==$platform){
                return $this->getArcadeHits($title);
            }
            else{
                return $this->getDataTGDB($title,$platform);
            }
        } else{
            else return $this->printJsonArray($datas->first());
        }
    }


}
?>
```

Comment: ... I use a Linode platform and once I faced the same problem. Just rebooted the machine (virtual server machine) and everything work great again. I think some "ghost code" maybe running on background without me knowing! You should give it a try (if you're able to)

And I'm also making a RESTful API!

Comment: @DennisBraga Unfortunately I can't reboot, but when I'm not using the API, CPU usage is 0%, so it's my code. I guess I should implement something to prevent request flood or a queue system so that only 2-3 requests are done together, while the other clients have to wait in line.

Comment: Took a look into your code. You're making calls that are put "on hold" while you retrieve data from others servers. Think that there's your problem. Try to work that part out and I think you're gonna be just fine.

Comment: P.S.: Try to read the Lavarel Code's Guide. There gonna be some nice tips for [codding](http://laravel.com/docs/contributing#coding-guidelines).

Comment: @DennisBraga the problem is that I should set a max number of requests that can be processed at same time, because even when the API is returning all cached data the CPU load is high. I tested it by adding a pause of 500ms between each request and CPU load dropped to 5-10%. The solution would be a queue system. For example I could create a "lock" and call `usleep` until the lock is open again.

Comment: "one of the possible" solutions, you might say so. But, yes... that may work for you! =D

Comment: ...and the code standards that I've talked about it, they may speed up your code. Trust me, they do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to retrieve data from others' servers. That is putting your CPU "on hold" until the data is fully retrieved. That's what is making your code be so "CPU expensive" ***(couldn't find other stuff that fits here =/ )***, cause your script is waiting until the data is received and then release the script (CPU) work.

I **strongly** suggest that you make asynchronous calls. That would release your CPU to work on the code, while other part of your system is getting the information you need.

I hope that'll be some help! =D

**UPDATE**
To make examples, I'd have to re-factor your code (and I'm lazy as anything!). But, I can tell you for sure: If you put your request code, those who make calls to others site's XML, onto a queue you would gain a lot of free CPU time. Every request are redirected for a queue. Once they're ready, you treat them as you wish. Laravel has a beautiful way for dealing with queues.

Comment: Some example on how to do this would help :)

Comment: @Vektor88 Added a update. Sorry for not be more directly on the first time.

Comment: what I'm missing about queues is that I understood how they work and how to implement them, but in all the examples the fire function stores the processed result instead of returning it to the client. That's what I wasn't able to find.

Comment: You can always put the result on a JSON file writen on the disk (on the queue precess) and verifies when they are ready (on the controller process)! It's the "dummy" way of doing it. Certainly you'll find some more interesting ways around the web. But, that's how I'd do it!

Comment: `while(true) {if(Cache::has($key)) {return Cache::get($key); break;} else usleep(250000); }` or you've a better idea? :)

Comment: In the Laravel's queue API, there's a way of puting things "on hold" and checking on them. You can create a JOB for this. Take a look at [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/queues#running-the-queue-listener).

Basicaly, a queue who listen to a queue (mind blown, I know)

Comment: I don't have the possibility to run a queue locally, in fact I'll use iron.io services

Comment: I have finally decided that host an API wasn't a good idea, so instead of making a xml/html to json wrapper for my client app, I'll let the app parse the xml/html from the original service which is enabled to bear such amount of work. But if I had to go on this strategy, this would've been the definitive answer, I'd have moved my API to a VPS or dedicated server, maybe paired with a second one for workers.

Answer (score 2):

what I would do first is to use a profiler to find out which parts would need an optimization. You can use for example this:

http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler

As well you didn't specify what kind of cpu is it, how many cores are you using? Is this a problem that your cpu is getting used that high?

Comment: I'm running the service on a shared host that runs on a Xeon CPU (E3-1230v2) where I have 1 core reserved, it's a problem that my CPU is used that high because it's just me using it. What if many people use it together?

Comment: First try to profile your code and if you can do nothing, upgrade your hosting plan. By the way 1700 requests in how many time?

Comment: I am sending the requests from an Android client, they're processed sequentially but only 2 at the same time.

Comment: I ported the installation to my local environment, with dual E5440 and 8GB Ram DDR2-ECC, where I installed xampp and enabled xdebug, so i was able to generate cachegrind file. Task manager says that httpd uses 10-15% CPU when fetching data and 35% when returning cached data. I'm not fully confident with the KCachegrind, but I only see data about the time needed by a function to finish and all the functions except the ones to fetch html/xml have shorter times.

Comment: I think this could be more a comment than a answer itself. It doesn't solve the problem, so...

Comment: Yeah that's true, but this gives ideas on where to focus for optimization. I'm not quite sure that it's the fact of fetching pages that induce a high cpu load. I would instead suspect the parsing of the html page which use the function `file_get_html`. We won't know without trying.

Answer (score 1):

you should use Laravel's Queue system along with beanstalkd for example and then monitor the queue (worker) with artisan queue:listen